# getting count of each category filtered by another table's field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables with the following structure.

`AD_TABLE`  -

```
               ID|NAME|CAT_ID|TYPE
               1| car | C0101|Sale
               2|bike | C0201|Want
```

`CAT_TABLE` -

```
              ID   |NAME          |PARENT|LEVEL
              C0100|Vehicle       |C0100 |    0
              C0101|Car           |C0100 |    1
              C0200|Bike/Scooters |C0100 |    1
              C0201|Bike          |C0200 |    2
              C0202|Scooter       |C0200 |    2
```

I need to get the count of ADs from each category, I have written the following query.

```
SELECT `CAT_TABLE`.`ID`,`CAT_TABLE`.`NAME`,`CAT_TABLE`.`LEVEL`,`CAT_TABLE`.`PARENT`, COUNT(`AD_TABLE`.`ID`) 
FROM `CAT_TABLE` 
LEFT JOIN `AD_TABLE` ON `AD_TABLE`.`CAT_ID`=`CAT_TABLE`.`ID`
WHERE (`CAT_TABLE`.`ID`='C0100' OR `CAT_TABLE`.`PARENT`='C0100') AND `AD_TABLE`.`TYPE`='0'
GROUP BY `CAT_TABLE`.`ID`
```

I got the count of each categories properly but after including the AD_TABLE`.`TYPE`='0' in the where clause categories which do not have ADs were ignored. I need to get all the categories even if the count is 0.

Comment: If you want to count `NULL`s as well, use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: COUNT(*) won't work. The problem is with the WHERE condition -> `AD_TABLE`.`TYPE`='0'. If I leave it out I get the counts properly but it would count of other types as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT     `CAT_TABLE`.`ID`,`CAT_TABLE`.`NAME`,`CAT_TABLE`.`LEVEL`,`CAT_TABLE`.`PARENT`,      COUNT(`AD_TABLE`.`ID`) 
    FROM       `CAT_TABLE` 
    LEFT JOIN  `AD_TABLE` 
    ON         `AD_TABLE`.`CAT_ID`=`CAT_TABLE`.`ID`
    AND        `AD_TABLE`.`TYPE`='0'  -- Write and here..<br/>
    WHERE      (`CAT_TABLE`.`ID`='C0100' OR `CAT_TABLE`.`PARENT`='C0100')
    GROUP BY   `CAT_TABLE`.`ID`
```

Comment: this worked thanks. Is there a way to get the addition of count for each as well. Eg: Vehicles count should be addition of cars & Bikes/scooters. And Bikes/Scooters count should be the addition of Bikes & Scooters.